# Permission on files created by nginx

Tags: file, nginx, permissions

I have a problem with the permissions of the files generated by my web server : nginx.
When a client uploads files on the server, it has 644 permission (with user/group : apache:apache).
But this file have to be modified by a designer (who is a member of apache group), but with 644 permissions it's no possible.
I have to change manually (or with a script) the files permissions every minutes.

How can I change the umask of the files created ? from 644 to 664 for example.
I don't know how to do that.
I have tried to change the umask of the system but it doesn't work for the files created by my webserver so ... can you help me ?

(Sorry for my bad english, i'm french :/ )

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.
I post it here, it could help other persons in the future.

So, I have modify */etc/sysconfig/php-fpm* to add :

> `umask 0002`

also add the line

> `. /etc/sysconfig/php-fpm`

in */etc/init.d/php-fpm*

then restart php-fpm

It works !